# Phlaconphp - how to add this validator in dependency injection?

Tags: php, phalcon

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ValidatorInterface;

class MaxMinValidator extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{

    public function validate($model)
    {
        $field = $this->getOption('field');

        $min = $this->getOption('min');
        $max = $this->getOption('max');

        $value = $model->$field;

        if ($min <= $value && $value <= $max) {
            $this->appendMessage(
                "The field doesn't have the right range of values",
                $field,
                "MaxMinValidator"
            );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've read the [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#registering-services-in-the-container). The below injects the shared service (it will be created upon the first request and reused upon all the following requests).

```
//Using an anonymous function, the instance will be lazy loaded
$di->setShared("minMaxValidator", function() {
    return new MaxMinValidator();
});
```

Also keep in mind, though you can inject into `DI` anything you can, it doesn't mean that you should do that. Smaller things like validators are normally model / form specific, i.e., they are rarely by definition a global service. To keep your `DI` from over-bloating you can "inject" them into particular model or form as a static property accessible with the right visibility. More over, unless you are instantiating gadzillions of them, injecting vs. instantiating will not make significant impact on the overall performance.

Comment: man, i have made an acl component for phalcon, i appreciate that you look and give me your personal opinion, in minutes i'll share you the link, and do you know something about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900005/how-to-make-a-multiple-node-js-chat-like-facebook thanks